# How to get Date format like this in android?

Tags: java, android, date-format

How to get Date format like this?

```
Saturday,Dec 11,2011
```

Edited:

My code portion is like the following:

```
   String outDate = "";
    Date dT = new Date(year, mon, day);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE,MMM dd,yyyy");
    outDate = sdf.format(dT);

and its output is `Sat,Dec 02,3911` when year = 2011,mon = 11,day = 2;
```

what is the reason of giving wrong month and year in output?

Comment: where u get year,month and date variable from? and if you are not getting correct value of year,month and day then use thisprivate Calendar calSelected = Calendar.getInstance();  int ziYear = calSelected.get(Calendar.YEAR);
      int ziMonth = (calSelected.get(Calendar.MONTH));
      int ziDay = calSelected
        .get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Try:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE,MMM dd,yyyy");
String text = formatter.format(...);
```

That will use the default locale - adjust accordingly for a different one.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this function

```
 Date today=new Date();
        public String getCurrentTime()
        {

         SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE,MM,dd,YYYY");
         String ClsCurrentDay = sdf.format(today);
         return ClsCurrentDay;
        }
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using Pascal case for variables, or having a static variable for today's date (which should keep changing, after all).

Comment: You still haven't fixed it, move the declaration inside the function.

Comment: we can set date as a global variable and i declare one function in which we can use that variable